# Duplicate type names in web service get switched in generated client

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, asmx

In an ASMX web service outside of my control there are 2 types each in a different namespace:

- `Range` (From - To)
- `Range` (Totally other properties)

When I generate a service reference, this generates the types `Range` and `Range1` in the proxy. But for some reason they seem to switcharoo from time to time when I update this reference, meaning that `Range1` suddenly became `Range` and vice versa.

This breaks code that relied on those types. Is there a way to force those classes to have a certain 'generation number'? So `Range` stays `Range` and `Range1` stays `Range1`?

Comment: I have excluded the (IMHO) irrelevant text. See the revision history if you want to restore some of it.

Comment: Thx, the question seems more clear now indeed.